# ListView is getting populated with same values

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, arraylist, listadapter

What happens is that I have a ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> and when I loop through that list in order to add the pair to a listview with two separate columns using a list adapter, I try to add the pair's first string to a certain textview and then the second string to certain textview, then it loops through the whole list and then adds in identical values to all lines.

Code for list adapter:

```
package com.example.test2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Pair;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ThreeColumn_ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Pair<String, String>> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> news;
    private int mViewResourceId;


    public ThreeColumn_ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> news) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, news);
        this.news = news;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);
        TextView firstName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textFirstName);
        TextView lastName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLastName);
        //TextView favFood = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textFavFood);

        Log.i("n2",news.toString());
        for(int j=0;j<news.size();j++){
           firstName.setText(news.get(j).first);
           lastName.setText(news.get(j).second);

        }


        return convertView;
    }

    }
```

What is stored in ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> news:

```
[Pair{usd -0.8068}, Pair{eur 0.5327}, Pair{gbp 1.2172}, Pair{nzd -2.7538}, Pair{cad 0.7586}, Pair{aud -1.7719}, Pair{chf 0.9591}, Pair{jpy 1.8649}]
```

Output viewed in listview layout:
`Pair{jpy 1.8649}` with pair's first value in textview `firstName` iterated 8 times and the pair's second value in textview `lastName` iterated 8 times and the 8 being the length of the `ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> news`

Comment: what is "n2" in Log.i

Comment: That is what is stored in the news list so the second code showing a list ; [Pair{usd -0.8068}, Pair{eur 0.5327}, Pair{gbp 1.2172}, Pair{nzd -2.7538}, Pair{cad 0.7586}, Pair{aud -1.7719}, Pair{chf 0.9591}, Pair{jpy 1.8649}]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, all I had to do was remove the for loop and do just news.get(position).first instead of doing a loop for news, since listview does a loop naturally.

So previously:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);
        TextView firstName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textFirstName);
        TextView lastName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLastName);
        //TextView favFood = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textFavFood);

        Log.i("n2",news.toString());
        for(int j=0;j<news.size();j++){
           firstName.setText(news.get(j).first);
           lastName.setText(news.get(j).second);

        }


        return convertView;
    }
```

Correct Way:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);
        TextView firstName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textFirstName);
        TextView lastName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLastName);
        //TextView favFood = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textFavFood);
        firstName.setText(news.get(position).first);
        lastName.setText(news.get(position).second);


        return convertView;
    }
```